# c# html agility pack pulling strings from html source code

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I am just learning html agility pack and would like to extract a couple pieces of data from a website.
I want to store the item name and price into strings. I have html source code that contains 25 products
with 1 segment of the code posted below

I have very little xpath and html agility pack experience. and I am working on a class project to compare lowes and home depot prices for a few items.

I want to save string data_price = "14.97";  and string item = "Leaktite 5-Gal. Blue Bucket (Pack of 3)"

### below is a portion of the source code I am working with

```
<div class="pod-inner">
                <div class="productlist plp-pod__compare">
                                <div class="checkbox-btn js-podclick-analytics" data-podaction="compare">
                                        <input type="checkbox" data-img="https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/8c1c50a0-e17c-4624-9e9e-35653052c1ce/svn/leaktite-paint-buckets-lids-209334-64_400_compressed.jpg" data-uom="&nbsp;/package" data-price="$14.97" data-title="Leaktite 5-Gal. Blue Bucket (Pack of 3)" value="203924937" id="compare203924937" name="product" autocomplete="off" class="checkbox-btn__input">
```

---

so far I got

```
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();    
            string home_bucket_url="https://www.homedepot.com/s/5%2520gallon%2520bucket?NCNI-5";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string home_bucket_raw = client.DownloadString(home_bucket_url);
            var findclasses = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input type").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("checkbox"));
            foreach (var x in findclasses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you successfully selected node that you need (please debug to make sure), what you can do is simply get the attribute values that you need. Something like this:

```
x.Attributes["data-price"].Value;
x.Attributes["data-title"].Value;
```